# commerce.js fulfillment method

Tags: http-status-code-422, commerce.js

I'm working on the ecommerce project and I get this response
 Validation/missing fields
index.js:1 fulfillment.shipping_method: The shipping method field is required

Here is what my orderData looks like

```
   const orderData={
      line_items:checkoutToken.live.line_items,
      customer:{firstname:shippingData.firstname,lastname:shippingData.lastName,
email:shippingData.email},
      shipping:{name:'International',street:shippingData.address1,
      town_city:shippingData.city,
      county_state:shippingData.shippingSubdivision,
      postal_zip_code:shippingData.zip,
      country:shippingData.shippingCountry},
      fullfillment:{shipping_method:shippingData.shippingOption},
      payment:{
        gateway:'stripe',
        stripe:{
          payment_method_id:paymentMethod.id }}}
```